# Yesod site links to localhost CSS files

Tags: haskell, heroku, yesod

I'm deploying a Yesod app to Heroku rouhghly following [these](http://blog.begriffs.com/2013/08/deploying-yesod-to-heroku-with-postgres.html) instructions. I can deploy perfectly, but when I visit [the site](http://floating-castle-2421.herokuapp.com/), it is unstyled. That seems to be because it's looking for some odd stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/static/combined/DtHk9AMk.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/static/tmp/UEG9zQsl.css">
```

Why is Yesod generating these URLs? The Procfile [specifies](https://github.com/eightyeight/floating-castle-2421/blob/master/Procfile#L90) running the Yesod executable in production mode...

Comment: What is `approot` set to?  This will either be set in your `Yesod` instance declaration or pulled as a setting from the `config/settings.yml` depending on how you started your project.  The latter is the default when using scaffolding.

Comment: @AndrewMyers Ahaha. Okay, there's the problem. Thanks! Sorry for being dumb :P. I'm now looking for a way to specify ApprootRelative from `config.yml`.

Comment: No problem, I knew to ask that because I did the same thing on my first Yesod project :)

Comment: The yesod book says that the default is ApprootRelative, which seems to be the case in the [code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-core/1.2.4/doc/html/src/Yesod-Core-Class-Yesod.html#approot).  If you remote the approot setting from the .yml file does it default to relative?

Comment: Cool, I'll post an answer summarizing the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yesod expects the `approot` in the Yesod type class to match the root url where it's hosted.  How this is used is explained in the Yesod book [here](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/yesod-typeclass).  If you use the scaffolding generated by `yesod init` the approot will come from the `config/settings.yml` file.

Since the default is `AppRootRelative` you can remove the `approot` settings from the `settings.yml` file and get the behavior you want.